# How can I read QR code generated by Pix payment with ReactJs and grab recipient information?

Tags: reactjs, qr-code

I need to create a QR code reader with ReactJs that reads the Qr code generated by the Pix payment method, allowing me to grab all the information the recipient has entered.
Does anyone know of a library that does this?

I've tried react-qr-reader and react-qr-scanner, but none can get the information from the return.
All help is welcome, thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.